# How to minify an AMD-Typescript browser project

Tags: javascript, typescript, minify

I have a [Typescript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) project with the following structure:

```
myproject
 |
 +-src
 |  |
 |  +-main.ts
 |  +-stringHandler.ts
 |  +-disposable.ts
 |  +-tsconfig.ts
 +-out
```

I am using [AMD](http://requirejs.org/) and compile the project using: `tsc --project src` with the following `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES5",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "module": "amd",
        "outDir": "../out"
    },
    "files": [
        "main.ts",
        "stringHandler.ts",
        "disposable.ts"
    ]
}
```

### The problem of generating the output

My problem is that, when I compile, I get the following:

```
myproject
 |
 +-out
    |
    +-main.js
    +-stringHandler.js
    +-disposable.js
```

But I would like to generate minified files! But how to do this? Each `.js` file has references to other `.js` files. I cannot simply rename all to `.min.js` because it would not work.

What is the best practice for this?
Thanks

Comment: Try using the `out` compiler option instead of `outDir` to generate one js file and then minimise it.

Comment: That is not recommended approach and also I am using `AMD` for loading those modules... it would be pointless to use AMD and then create one js-ball!

Comment: I thought one of the advantages of AMD/requireJS is the ability to load all modules in one download. See http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html

Comment: @billc.cn AMD stands for "Asynchronous Module Definitions". It loads asynchronously on demand... so if you never need a particular module it will never load and if you do, it does.

Comment: Realistically, the overhead of making a large amount of HTTP requests to load each module individually can be worse than the overhead of loading one big ball of code. And telling your webserver to gzip the script will yield more benefit than minifying it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate `.min.js` files and shim...

```
requirejs.config({
    enforceDefine: true,
    paths: {
        jquery: [
            'lib/jquery.min',
            'lib/jquery'
        ]
    }
});
```

Okay for one or two files, but not for your whole project... so option two is to minify your files into a folder and allow them to keep their original names.

The third option would be to adjust RequireJS itself to look for ".min.js" rather than ".js".

Option four is to use the RequireJS optimizer, which will actually create a single file by looking through all of your code and sorting out the modules... leaving you with a big ball of JavaScript at the end.